# Calendar as view's pager (passing arguments between views?)

Tags: views, paging, datetime

I have a view paged by week. Users are a bit disappointed by the pager: they find clumsy to navigate to weeks that are far in time (more than 1 month from today's date).

The idea is to keep the weekly pager for small jumps in time and add a month calendar, so when you click a day on the calendar, the corresponding week is shown in the view. If this is too complicated, I think that a drop-down with a list of weeks could be enough, at least for now.

I was thinking that a possible solution could be creating two views and display them in one page. When you click a cell in the first view (which shows the month calendar), the date is passed to the second view (the main view, paged by week), which accepts a date as a contextual filter. But is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two Views should be possible with the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module:

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

or the side by side could be accomplished by integrating the Views into the [Panels Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels):

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
>   manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
>   within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to
>   create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even
>   override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you
>   can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
>   permissions.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late response, I had no time to work on this issue. I used the first module and a custom calendar-datebox.tpl.php in order to link every day of the month calendar to the week of the second view. It feels like a hack, but it works.